# How many touches can I recognize using Hammer JS?

Tags: multi-touch, hammer.js

I would like to know how many touches I can manage using [Hammer JS](https://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/).

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Does it mean you want to handle multiple events like pinch, swipe, pan on same html element?

Comment: What I mean is how many are the touch points that are recognized. One finger, two fingers, three ... at most how many? In any case, I solved the problem using another language. Thanks.